# Hashing a string using the algorithm that Linux uses to hash users' passwords?

Tags: php, encryption, hash

What's the algorithm that Linux uses to hash users' passwords? How can I implement that algorithm in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to know some background information on Linux password storage formats - especially on shadowed password configuration before you can actually implement your own.

On Linux distributions using [glibc2](http://linux.about.com/cs/linux101/g/glibc2.htm), the hash function has a 'magic bit' and salt prefixed to it.

The magic bit starts off with '$x$' and is used to determined the hash function that was used:

- $1$ for MD5
- $2$ for Blowfish,
- $5$ for SHA-256 and
- $6$ for SHA-512

(Other unix systems like NetBSD might have different values for this).

The magic bit then followed by 8 bits that constitutes the salt and optionally is terminated by another "$". Between this and the next "$", you will find the actual password hash.

Almost all modern Linux systems these days do NOT store the passwords in the world-readable `/etc/passwd`. Instead the passwords are shadowed in `/etc/shadow` where only root is allowed read permission. If the shadowed password scheme in use, the `/etc/passwd` file shows a character such as '*', or 'x' instead of the password.

The format of a typical password in `/etc/shadow` would looks like this:

```
$a:$b:$c:$e:$f:$g:$h:$i
```

Where:

**$a**: username

**$b**: salt and hashed password (as explained above). If this is "NP" or "!" or null then it means that the account has no password. "LK" or "*" means the account is locked and the user will be unable to log-in. "!!" means that the password has expired

**$c**: Days since epoch of last password change

**$d**: Days until change allowed

**$e**: Days before change required

**$f**: Days warning for expiration

**$g**: Days before account inactive

**$h**: Days since epoch when account expires

**$i**: Reserved for future use.

An example of a shadowed password file could be found at: http://configuration.logfish.net/index.php/etc/shadow

**References:**

[crypt(3) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt)

[Why shadow your passwd file?](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Shadow-Password-HOWTO-2.html)

[Understanding Linux Password Hashes](http://www.digitalpeer.com/id/understanding)

[Shadow password on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_password)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the PHP [`crypt` function](http://www.php.net/crypt).

Comment: Does the `crypt()` function always use the same salt as the one uses by the OS?